# Php PDO rowCount() return wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a function for getting path in a tree structure data.

According to my table in DB, root should get no result when I query `sub_id='root_id'`

When I just pass the root the rowCount return correct result which is `0`. However when I pass a node from lower rank(3rd), in the end of the recursive which is root, rowCount return 1?

**PS**

I use Mysql as DB

This is my table

```
main_id | sub_id
----------------    
    1   |    2    
    1   |    3    
    2   |    4    
    3   |    5
```

The code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("Select * from table where sub_id= ? ");  

function get_path($stmt,$node,&$map){

    $res=$stmt->execute(array($node));

    if(!$res){ throw new Exception( implode(' ',$stmt->errorInfo()),1); }

        echo $node.' found '.$stmt->rowCount().'<br>';

        if($stmt->rowCount()==0){ //root
            $map[]=$node;
        }else{

            foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) AS $row){
                $map[]=$node;
                $upper_node=$row['main_id'];
                get_path($stmt,$upper_node,$map);
        }
    }

}
```

If I just pass `get_path($stmt,1,$map);` (the root)

the output:

```
1 found 0
```

but when I for example pass `4` into it
the output become:

```
4 found 1
2 found 1
1 found 1 <= it should found 0
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on PDOStatement::rowCount() to get the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement, see [PHP manual, PDOStatement::rowCount](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

> DOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the
> last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding
> PDOStatement object.
>
> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
> a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
> returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
> for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
> applications.

[...]

> Example #2 Counting rows returned by a SELECT statement
>
> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the
> number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use
> PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same
> predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use
> PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will
> be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.

Comment: I found many discussion said rowCount only can work normal with MySQL, so I thought it would work, but I gusess it does not.  Many thanks

Comment: Can I use PDOStatement::execute() to do the Select Count(*) statement? Then use the fetchColumn()? will this be reliable too? Because I hope to use prepare statement.

Comment: Yes, this will be reliable.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably something to do with this from [PDO rowCount Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

"If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications."

In other words `rowCount` only really works with DML, and I believe this is the case in MySQL.

You have to count the fetched results to get the guaranteed row count.

Comment: this is a recursive function, pass 4 into the function will trace up the tree.

Comment: @Anna Sorry, I misunderstood your qu.. thanks for making it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Eg of @VMai 's Correct Answer:

```
$query = $db->prepare("

  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
  WHERE
       whatever
 ");

$query->execute();

$result = $query->fetchColumn();

if ($result > 5)
{
echo "Result is greater than 5";
}
else
{
echo "Result is less than 5";
}
?>
```

Note: You will need to run the "real" SQL Query again, except without COUNT(*).