# PHP: rowCount() now accurate counting?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this query:

```
$butacas= $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM `usuarios` WHERE `sala` LIKE :nombreSala');
$butacas->bindValue(':nombreSala', $nombreSala);
$butacas->execute();
echo $butacas->rowCount();
```

This query results in an integer: 1

if I replace `:nombreSala` with the value that actually exists in the database, like:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM usuarios WHERE sala LIKE 'salaChica'
```

It still results in 1.

Now, when checking the database with phpMyadmin I realise that with that value (salaChica) there are 2 items instead of one! (and consulting from phpMyadmin does result in 2).

[image]

Why it is not accurate? I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034652/php-pdo-rowcount-return-wrong-result) about that function not being always accurate with SELECT, but is there a simple alternative?

Comment: In PHP, you just ask for a count, it's always only 1 value in the rowCount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing the number of rows returned (1) with the value returned (2).
Your query "SELECT count(*) WHERE whatever" will always return 1 row (unless you do a group by). that row contains a single column - the value of that column will be the count - 2 in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo $butacas->fetchColumn();
```

instead of

```
echo $butacas->rowCount();
```