# Why does not the fetch statement have any value after the fetch_all statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to output the number of myTable and output field1 of myTable in the loop.

However, if I run the following code, only 10 'test : ' will be printed.

If I remove `[$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);]` and change the `$count of for()` to `10`, it works fine, but that is not what I intended.

```
<?php
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8;", myid, mypw);
$statement = $db->query('select field1 from myTable limit 10');
$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = count($rows);
echo "count : $count<br><br>";
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo 'test : '.$row['field1'].'<br>';
}
?>
```

I would like to avoid the following methods to count the number of myTable. Because query statements that look similar are added unnecessarily.

```
$count = $db->query('SELECT count(*) FROM qudtls_mutter')->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Use ```foreach($rows as $rowno => $row) ``` instead.

Comment: Is there any way to handle it using for() statement?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you want a counter, that's easy enough as well. But using the foreach is simple and less likely to break if you make changes elsewhere.

Comment: I was trying to use a `for()` statement for consistency, but now I can see the advantage of `foreach()`. Thank you. @SloanThrasher

Comment: Statement results are cursor-based. `fetchAll` reads everything and moves the cursor to the end of the result-set. AFAIK, there is no way to rewind the cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the result, from

```
$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

will be associative array, that you will need to count.

You can simply use [`$statement->rowCount():int`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) that will return count from last query.

Then you can use it mixed with `FOR`

```
for ($i=0; $i<$statement->rowCount(); $i++) {

}
```

For other use, you can go with `WHILE`

```
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

}
```

For use `foreach`, simply:

```
foreach ($statment as $row) {

}
```

Comment: I tried using rowCount () but I get an error saying **Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::rowCount()**. I think that I can not use rowCount () in **select** statements.

Comment: @gainacho Provide in with version of PHP you are working?

Comment: my PHP version is 7.0.20.

Comment: I found that, I had bug in example: you should call `$statement->rowCount()`, not `$db->rowCount()`. Still found this error? @gainacho

Comment: Yes, it is my mistake. Now I can count the number of `select` statements using rowCount (). Thank you. However, according to the `PDOStatement :: rowCount` in PHP.net manual, 'this behavior is not guaranteed for all databases' about rowCount (). Is it a safe way?

Comment: Yes, you are right, but if you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034652/php-pdo-rowcount-return-wrong-result), for mysql should be ok. If you DB will be big, then you should use `SELECT COUNT(id)` query for optimization. You asked about, how to make it use with `FOR`, not about best optimization.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8;", myid, mypw);
> $statement = $db->query('select field1 from myTable limit 10');
> $rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
> ```

The above will, as it says, *`fetch All`* of the ten rows. **There will be now no more rows to `fetch`** in your result set. This is to be expected.

Change this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to this:

```
foreach ($rows as $i => $row) {
```

to have it work. After the `fetchAll` you already have all the rows, you do not need to fetch them again, **and it will not work if you try to**.

If you want to output the whole table, do not fetchAll, but fetch until there is nothing left. Remove the fetchAll, and:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $i++;
    // This will execute for all rows. It will exit as soon as fetch() returns null at the end of the query.
```