# Count returns wrong number of rows in Laravel/Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I'm running two Laravel (front)/Lumen (api) applications that are using the same DB. (I'm aware that the seperation might not be ideal, but this is only for testing).

When I count the number of rows in each application the (front) returns 50000 (correct - when i query the db) rows and api returns 50001. Always one off.

I tried, when outputting, to count the number of rows to see if it was just the rowCount method that was wrong, but it does indeed output 50001 rows. With that many rows it difficult to see which row exactly is wrong.

I stumbled across this: [Php PDO rowCount() return wrong result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034652/php-pdo-rowcount-return-wrong-result)

I'm always running:

```
DB::connection()->getPdo()->prepare($query)
```

to get the rows.

And then originally: 
`result->rowCount`

Changed to counting separately - as per suggestion:

```
$count = DB::connection()->getPdo()->query("SELECT count(*) AS cnt )->fetchColumn(0);
```

Then:

```
DB::table()->select()->count()
```

And lastly:

```
DB::table()->select('SELECT count(*) as cnt)->value('cnt')
```

But all returns exactly one row more. I'm also aware that they probably all fall back on PDO.

My first reaction was that it was a transaction, but I'm not using any, so only if there is something built-in by default in Lumen/Laravel?

Comment: use PDOStatement::execute() to do the Select Count(*) statement? Then use the fetchColumn()?

Comment: Same result as before.